# How to prevent from input value lost, created by multiple select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
    <select id="additional" name="additional" multiple="">
        <option value="Shipping Expences">Shipping Expences</option>
        <option value="Packaging Expences">Packaging Expences</option>
        <option value="Comission Expences">Comission Expences</option>
        <option value="something">something</option>
        <option value="hnjghj">hnjghj</option>
    </select>
    <div id="add-amt"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery('#additional').change(function(){
  jQuery('#add-amt').html("");
  jQuery('#additional > option:selected').each(function() {
      var val = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery('#add-amt').append('<div class="col-sm-3"><div><label>'+val+' Amount</label></div><input type="text" name="additional['+val+']" placeholder="'+val+'"></div>');
  });
});
```

The code is working fine. But there is a problem. 
If I select something it will create a input field according to select. Then if I write something in the jquery generated input and again if I select another option from the select, that time it is erasing the old input as well as the value what I was written in the input.

Expected Output: In jquery generated input, if I write something it should be contain the same value after select another option from multiple select.

: Any help??

Comment: Yes I have tried with removing the line. Unfortunately it's causing duplicate field rendering, which I don't want. Any other way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove the line `jQuery('#add-amt').html("");` .its will empty the div each time  of change select option

**Updated**

1. *Prevent the duplicate append*
2. **Deselect option updated**
3. create the array . validate each selected is not array .Then push the selected value to the array.In this time duplicate value not appended

```js
var arr=[];
jQuery('#additional').change(function() {
 // jQuery('#add-amt').html("");

  jQuery('#additional > option:selected').each(function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
   var res = jQuery('#additional > option:selected').map(function(){
                return $(this).val()
   }).get()
    if(!arr.includes(val)){
       arr.push(val)
    jQuery('#add-amt').append('<div class="col-sm-3" data-value="'+val+'"><div><label>' + val + ' Amount</label></div><input type="text" name="additional[' + val + ']" placeholder="' + val + '"></div>');
    }
    else{
      arr.forEach(function(a,b){
           if(!res.includes(a)){
             arr.splice(b,1);
             $('div .col-sm-3[data-value="'+a+'"]').remove()
           }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="additional" name="additional" multiple="">
<option value="Shipping Expences">Shipping Expences</option>
<option value="Packaging Expences">Packaging Expences</option>
<option value="Comission Expences">Comission Expences</option>
<option value="something">something</option>
<option value="hnjghj">hnjghj</option>
</select>
<div id="add-amt"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's causing duplicate field rendering

Comment: @user2980415 see my updated answer.its was prevent the duplicate value append

Comment: really appreciable. But when I deselect, the inputs remain same. If I deselect, it should go. I think need to update the array.

Comment: @user2980415 .yes you are right see my latest updated answer.I was added with deselect option also

Comment: Working fine. Thanks

Comment: You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line, your previous content gets cleared:

```
jQuery('#add-amt').html("");
```

Removing it gets to your working output.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  jQuery('#additional').change(function(){
    jQuery('#add-amt').html("");
    jQuery('#additional > option:selected').each(function() {
      var val = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery('#add-amt').append('<div class="col-sm-3"><div><label>'+val+' Amount</label></div><input type="text" name="additional['+val+']" placeholder="'+val+'"></div>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<select id="additional" name="additional" multiple="">
  <option value="Shipping Expences">Shipping Expences</option>
  <option value="Packaging Expences">Packaging Expences</option>
  <option value="Comission Expences">Comission Expences</option>
  <option value="something">something</option>
  <option value="hnjghj">hnjghj</option>
</select>
<div id="add-amt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you made mistake `jQuery('#add-amt').html("");` you are removing html.

Try this one.

```js
jQuery('#additional').change(function(){
  //jQuery('#add-amt').html("");
  jQuery('#additional > option:selected').each(function() {
      var val = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery('#add-amt').append('<div class="col-sm-3"><div><label>'+val+' Amount</label></div><input type="text" name="additional['+val+']" placeholder="'+val+'"></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="additional" name="additional" multiple="">
        <option value="Shipping Expences">Shipping Expences</option>
        <option value="Packaging Expences">Packaging Expences</option>
        <option value="Comission Expences">Comission Expences</option>
        <option value="something">something</option>
        <option value="hnjghj">hnjghj</option>
    </select>
    <div id="add-amt"></div>
```